# Can't delete blob from windows azure storage when filename ends in question mark

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I've tried to delete some files ending in .jpg?12312223 and .jpg?zz=23 (random numbers) from windows azure management portal, but it never works. I've also tried to delete them from CloudBerry Explorer for Azure Blob Storage and get an Error.

Is there any way to delete those files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for another tool to do so, may I suggest you try **Azure Management Studio** from Cerebrata (http://www.cerebrata.com). This tool is currently in public beta and can be downloaded from Cerebrata's website home page (Disclosure: I'm part of Cerebrata team).

If you're trying to do it through storage client library, you can try something like this below:

```
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference("images");
        CloudBlockBlob blobWithSpecialCharacters = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("filename.txt?j=123123");
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This is sample text")))
        {
            blobWithSpecialCharacters.UploadFromStream(ms);
        }
        blobWithSpecialCharacters.Delete();
```

Comment: Thanks! I used your software and it worked, better and faster than CloudBerry.

Comment: Every answer to Azure storage from Gaurav is correct and upvote worthy. Nobody has been working at such a level of detail for so long.